# How to access state outside of a component

Tags: reactjs, state, router

I have an App component which Im trying to make a PrivateRoute like so:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      this.state.auth === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);
```

the problem is that this.state.auth is inside the App component and the Route is outside of the component so I dont have access to it, how can I get the boolean from the state?

PS. you did not understand the question:
this is my code to clarify:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import ChangePass from './components/ChangePass';
import MManager from './components/MManager';
import Mworker from './components/Mworker';
import Mclient from './components/Mclient';
import Login from './components/Login';
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      this.state.auth === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    id: '',
    password: '',
    role: '',
    token: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    auth: false,
    error: false
  };
```

As you can see the state is inside the App component, I want to access it in the PrivateRoute, how do I do that?

Comment: Please, update the question with example where you use PrivateRoute.

Comment: Are you using redux, or plan on using new react hooks to accomplish this?

Comment: @FrankerZ I'm not planning to use redux, its a small project so its not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the state into your Route/Private route component via props:

```
<App>
   <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.auth} ... />
</App>
```

And access it below:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      authed === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for parent state to be used in child components, it should be either passed as a prop:

```
<PrivateRoute auth={this.state.auth} component={...} />
```

This may be a problem if a component is deeply nested.

Alternatively, solutions for global state (context API, Redux, etc.) should be used to access global application state in nested components.

Comment: I checked it. It's still unclear where `<PrivateRoute>` is used. `App` is incomplete and doesn't contain `render`. This statement *this.state.auth is inside the App component and the Route is outside of the component so I dont have access to it* needs to be clarified. Usually `App` is root component, so other components should be its children, including `PrivateRoute`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ref`.

```
<PrivateRoute ref={i => this.my_ref = i} />
```

Somewhere in code

```
console.log(this.my_ref.state)
```